# Deploy rstatd on opensuse 11.3 linux for remote monitoring in Loadrunner

Tags: performance, unix, performance-testing, loadrunner, opensuse

I want to install and execute rstatd on opensuse linux for monitoring system resources. I am using rstatd because I am using LoadRunner tool for load testing which has support for rstatd for remote server monitoring.

With my installed opensuse version, rstatd was not pre-installed. I read somewhere that from opensuse 10+ version, rstatd doesn't come preinstalled.

I downloaded [rstatd](http://sourceforge.net/projects/rstatd/) package from sourceforge site. followed instructions present in README file. I was able to run rstatd server with the help of this [link](http://gadgetwiz.com/administration/rstatd.html) but no monitoring data was available on LR server. Later I thought it might be a firewall issue so I disabled the firewalls also, still couldn't see data on LR server.
All settings in LR are present and done according to LR documentation.

Any pointers would be helpful if anyone has faced such issue. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Your better solution is to take advantage of the license for SiteScope which comes with the license for LoadRunner. Then you only need SSH or Telnet access from the SiteScope host to the system being monitored. Once signed in the SiteScope agent will execute command line utilities to pull back system information.  There is no need to run RSTAT in such a case

The use of SiteScope has been the recommended and preferred version of Monitoring since its inclusion in version 8.x of LoadRunner.